# window.alert occuring twice with canvas collision

Tags: javascript, function, canvas, collision-detection, alert

For a canvas game I am in the process of making,

the collision condition I currently have means that a `window.alert` will be displayed in the browser window. However, due to the nature of the collision (too quick?) this `window.alert` appears twice, requiring 'OK' to be pressed a total of two times with the two alerts.

I have tried delaying the alert function using `setTimeout`/`setInterval` but this results in no change. This must be due to how much the sprites overlap when colliding?

Below is my collision condition, and my window alert I wish to be displayed only once after it occurs (so the game can be reset). How could I alter this to prevent more than one `window.alert` each time?

```
         if (x < object.x && x + width > object.x &&
         y < object.y + 60 && height + y > object.y + 60) {

        setTimeout(function() {
        window.alert("You lose");
        location.reload();
        }, 100); 
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of confirming "You lose" ? Why not just alert() it?

Comment: I could have it either though, right? I mean, I shouldn't really, but I could?
Anyway, thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 5):

Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

`setTimeout` occurs only once, `setInterval` is infinite.

Comment: I've used both timeout and interval through testing. I did initially have setTimeout, however, had no luck. I'll update my code though, to reflect your (more appropriate) recommendation! Thanks for your quick response :)